# Bash history expansion with tab completion

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I make frequent use of command history expansion using the form `!n:m`, where `n` is the number of the historical command and `m` is the number of the argument, or short forms thereof.

Is there a way to expand such arguments in situ, so that I can then tab-complete them?

A trivial example:

```
$ mycmd long/path/with/plenty/of/subdirectories/
$ cp !$/tediously-verbose-filename.txt .
```

I'd love to be able to use argument repetition without having to then type the filename out in full (or resort to dummy runs with `ls` or `echo`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conceptual terms you're looking for is [command] *history* and *history expansion* - if you run `man bash`, you'll find sections `HISTORY` and `HISTORY EXPANSION` devoted to this topic.

That said, in this particular case, it is not history expansion, but the **special shell variable `$_` that is your friend**:

It expands to the **last (expanded) argument of the most recent command**.

Try the following, which mimics your scenario:

```bsh
ls "$HOME"  

# Type this on the command line and press TAB (possibly twice)
# _before_ submitting to TAB-complete to matching files in "$HOME"
# (irrespective of what the current directory is).
# $_ at this point contains whatever "$HOME" expanded to, e.g. "/Users/jdoe".
cp $_/
```

Note: Whether tab-completion works for a given command is unrelated to whether `$_` is used or not. See `man bash`, section `Programmable Completion`, for how to manually enable tab-completion for commands of interest.

Comment: Thank you for the terminology. Should I update my question to reflect this?

Comment: @KateMcKenzie: Please do.

Comment: $_ sounds like what I want. And it does indeed contain the last argument of the most recent command. Sadly, it's not working for me, but perhaps I'm misinterpreting "Type this and press TAB _before_ submitting ...".

Comment: @KateMcKenzie: What bash version, what platform (mine: `bash 3.2.51` on `OS X 10.9.2`)? What, specifically, isn't working? What I meant is: on the command line, type `'cp $_/<start-of-filename-of-interest>'` _without pressing ENTER_, then -press TAB (potentially twice, depending on your settings) to expand to matching files in your home folder.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't quote the argument to the first command. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Actually, that was premature. It seems to work for echo but not for anything else. The dozen or so $__git variables may not be helping. I'll look further into the way bash is expanding env vars.

I'm using GNU bash 4.2.25 on Linux Mint Maya.

Comment: @KateMcKenzie: Please see the end of my updated answer; `bash` enables only a few completions out of the box (and cannot anticipate all the ones that make sense).

Answer (score 3):

Not *exactly* what the OP wants, but you could use readline shortcuts to retrieve a specific argument from a prior command, and the shortcut is `Alt+.`. For the specific example that OP gave, this works very well, with the following workflow:

```
$ mycmd long/path/with/plenty/of/subdirectories/
$ cp <Alt>+./tediously-verbose-filename.txt .
```

Here are a couple of additional things that I find very useful:

- If you continue to press `Alt+.`, it retrieves the last argument from prior commands in the history.
- You can prefix `Alt+.` with `Alt+<n>` where `n` is a digit from `0-9` to retrieve the specific argument. E.g., `Alt+0Alt+.` would retrieve the command itself and `Alt+1Alt+.` would retrieve the first parameter etc. You can then continue to press `Alt+.` without having to repeat the prefix.

NOTE: On terminals where `Alt` combination doesn't work, you could use `Esc` prefix, e.g., `<Esc>.`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, use the following:

```
cp !$:h/tediously-verbose-filename.txt
```

The `:h` part will bring the directory portion of the command argument

Comment: That isn't actually what I was after, although I can see it would be useful in other situations.

Perhaps I haven't been sufficiently clear in my question; I'll try to improve it.

Comment: This doesn't work _directly_ as @KateMcKenzie intended, but it does so in a _2-step_ process: first, type _and submit_ `cp !$:h/` (note the terminating `/`) - this will  _paste_ the command with the previous command's last argument substituted for `!$:h` onto the command line, followed by `/`, allowing you to _then_ TAB-complete; for a _1-step_ solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but looks like only option im seeing is running the command with `:p` to preview by printing to the screen, then arrow up in history to run it after editing.

I'm curious if a function could be created that pulls the results of `!!:p` then returns it to the line before the command is actually ran, initiated by a tab after `!!` for example.  Ill post it here if i manage to figure out how to write it.

but here is the example of what i mean:

```
cd@PC:~> _ zypper install git
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'git' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'git' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
cd@PC:~> !!:p
_ zypper install git
cd@PC:~> _ zypper install git-core
```